# Shared preference override element if same type

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences

I have a view where there are a few element (dropdown, chechbox...).

For the dropdown, I save the position of the selected item in my shared preferences. (so an int)

for the checkboxes, I wanted to store an Int (0 if false, else 1), but if the state of my checkbox is false (0), the selected value of the dropdown is the 0 item

Why ?

See my helper :

```
class PreferenceHelper(context: Context) {

    val PREFERENCE_NAME = "SharedPreference"
val PREFERENCE_DEPARTEMENT = "0"
val PREFERENCE_ACTU = false
val PREFERENCE_INFOS_PRATIQUE = false
val PREFERENCE_ALERTES = false


val preference = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
val editor = preference.edit()

fun getPreferenceAlert() : Boolean{
    return preference.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_ALERTES.toString(), false)
}

fun setPreferenceAlertes(checked : Boolean){
    preference.edit().putBoolean(PREFERENCE_ALERTES.toString(), checked).apply()
}
fun getPreferenceActu() : Boolean{
    return preference.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_ACTU.toString(), false)
}

fun setPreferenceActu(checked : Boolean){
    preference.edit().putBoolean(PREFERENCE_ACTU.toString(), checked).apply()
}
fun getPreferenceInfo() : Boolean{
    return preference.getBoolean(PREFERENCE_INFOS_PRATIQUE.toString(), false)
}

fun setPreferenceInfoPratique(checked : Boolean){
    preference.edit().putBoolean(PREFERENCE_INFOS_PRATIQUE.toString(), checked).apply()
}
fun getPreferenceDepartement() : Int{
    return preference.getInt(PREFERENCE_DEPARTEMENT, 0)
}

fun setPreferenceDepartement(position : Int){
    preference.edit().putInt(PREFERENCE_DEPARTEMENT, position).apply()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are converting the values of the preferences to strings instead of giving unique keys to each preference.

Comment: So what should I change ?

Comment: You were right, I juste change the value of each of my **val** to a key and it works. I thought the val was the key. Thanks !

Comment: Please improve your answer